# how to check some items in xceedsoftware.checkboxlist control in wpf window loading

Tags: wpf

i searched a lot for a solution for my problem but i did not find any answer . shortly i want to load my wpf window with selected item from checkbox list , i can not reach any checkbox in the list to make is selected property to true so here is my list i attached to the checkbox list :

```
List<PeriodicSpareParts> sp = new List<PeriodicSpareParts>();
        sp.Add(new PeriodicSpareParts { ID=1,SubjectName="Oil Filter" });
        sp.Add(new PeriodicSpareParts { ID = 2, SubjectName = "Air Filter" });
        sp.Add(new PeriodicSpareParts { ID = 3, SubjectName = "Gas Filter" });  

 CheckList.ItemsSource = sp;
        CheckList.DisplayMemberPath = "SubjectName";
        CheckList.ValueMemberPath = "ID";
```

and my checkboxlist in xaml:

```
<xctk:CheckListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="CheckList" Background="Transparent" FontFamily="century Gothic" FontSize="15" 
    BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" ItemSelectionChanged="CheckList_ItemSelectionChanged"/>
```

so please help me in finding a solution

Comment: Can you show your xaml for the checklist element?

Comment: <xctk:CheckListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="CheckList" Background="Transparent" FontFamily="century Gothic" FontSize="15"
                                       BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" ItemSelectionChanged="CheckList_ItemSelectionChanged"/>

Comment: xctk:CheckListBox is not a WPF element. What library are you using?

Comment: Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.CheckListBox

Comment: [this](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckListBox) library?

Comment: If your library is [this](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckListBox), I tested your code in [this](https://github.com/marlonedu/WpfTests/tree/master/WpfApp15) Github project (check the MainWindow class), but it seems to work fine. What is the problem to which you cannot find a solution?

Comment: I need to check some of the checkbox list in the widow load and i cannot reach that .

Comment: To be more specific when loading my window, the checkbox list has to check some items depend on my database data , i get my data from the database in a list and from this list as example my first item in the checkbox list has to be checked but i cannot reach the checkbox to make it checked so please help me in finding a solution or advise me with any alternative to the checkbox list

Comment: How do you know what items are you going to check? The List with the items that you are going to check is an List of ints with the ID of the PeriodicSpareParts?.

Comment: With the id , if the id from the database equal to the checkbox id , it has to be checked

Comment: Because in the load event i loading the list and telling it that the display-member is the periodicsparepart name and the value member with the id

Comment: I answered your question. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check some items of the CheckListBox in a different method than the one that sets the ItemsSource, you can do this:

1. Modify you PeriodicSpareParts class: add a property that maps the SelectedMemberPath of the CheckListBox. This new property can be named like you want, for my example, I named IsSelected.
2. Modify your PeriodicSpareParts class: implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to tell the WPF system that was a change in the property created in the step before.

   ```
   public class PeriodicSpareParts : INotifyPropertyChanged {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string SubjectName { get; set; }

       private bool isSelected;
       public bool IsSelected { 
           get => this.isSelected;
           set {
               this.isSelected = value;
               this.OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }


       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
           this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the loaded event, where you obtain the List with the IDs of the selected items, set the items with IsSelected=true in the ItemsSource property.

   ```
   private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
       var listOfPeriodicSparePartsIDsToCheck = new List<int> {2, 3};

       foreach (PeriodicSpareParts item in this.CheckList.ItemsSource) {
           if (listOfPeriodicSparePartsIDsToCheck.Any(x => x == item.ID))
               item.IsSelected = true;
       }
   }
   ```
4. In the constructor (or other method), set the ItemsSource property:

   ```
   public MainWindow() {
       InitializeComponent();

       List<PeriodicSpareParts> sp = new List<PeriodicSpareParts>();
       sp.Add(new PeriodicSpareParts { ID = 1, SubjectName = "Oil Filter", IsSelected = false });
       sp.Add(new PeriodicSpareParts { ID = 2, SubjectName = "Air Filter", IsSelected = false });
       sp.Add(new PeriodicSpareParts { ID = 3, SubjectName = "Gas Filter", IsSelected = false });
       sp.Add(new PeriodicSpareParts { ID = 4, SubjectName = "Another", IsSelected = false });

       CheckList.ItemsSource = sp;
       CheckList.DisplayMemberPath = "SubjectName";
       CheckList.ValueMemberPath = "ID";

       this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
   }
   ```
5. In the XAML, map the new property created in the step 1, to the SelectedMemberPath property:

   ```
   <xctk:CheckListBox
       Name="CheckList"
       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
       Margin="10,10,0,0"
       Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
       FontFamily="century Gothic" FontSize="15"
       ItemSelectionChanged="CheckList_ItemSelectionChanged"
       SelectedMemberPath="IsSelected" />
   ```

You can check this answer in [this](https://github.com/marlonedu/WpfTests/tree/master/WpfApp15) project.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort to answer me , but i apologize for asking more question i did not use mvvm i am using code behind , so how to do your answer with the code behind.

Comment: I'm not using mvvm, only code behind. The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is an interface that is only used in WPF and no affect to other frameworks

Comment: the last question , if i replaced the list with data table i get the following expection System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'BEL.PeriodicSpareParts'.'

Comment: I suggest that this last question you post like "new question", since it has a different scope that the original question. Furthermore, if this answer responds your initial question, mark it as answer